# Type Mismatch Error VBA - why?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a basic macro that is looking at a Cell in column B and then placing "NA" adjacent to the cell in column C based on the criteria I'm looking for. I have a type mismatch error and I don't understand why.

```
Sub badURLs()
    Dim lr As Long ' Declare the variable
    lr = Range("B2:B23068").End(xlUp).Row ' Set the variable
    ' lr now contains the last used row in column A

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For a = lr To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, a, "bloomberg" Or "wiki" Or "hoovers", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'Compares for bloomberg, wiki, or hoovers. Enters loop if value is greater than 0
            With Cells(a, 3)
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = "NA"
            End With
        End If
    Next a

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The mismatch error occurs here:

```
With Cells(a, 3)
```

Comment: Is it possible that the `lr` is ever be 0?  Does it occur the first time the `For` loop runs?  Also, add `Option Explicit` to the very top of your sub, and add `Dim a as Long` (or a quickhand way is `Dim a&`).

Comment: What is the value of "a" when the program hits the error? Hover the mouse over the variable "a" to see what it is. I also note that your lr (lastrow) variable is being taken from column B, not column A as your comment suggests. Check which columns you're interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are getting the error on the `With Cells(a, 3)` line?? I imagine you're getting the error on the `If InStr` line because that line is completely invalid syntax.  It should be:

```
    If InStr(1, Cells(a, 3), "bloomberg", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
    Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 3), "wiki", vbTextCompare) > 0 _
    Or InStr(1, Cells(a, 3), "hoovers", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

Comment: You are correct the error was due to the incorrect syntax of InStr. I haven't used it much so I'm still learning how to use it correctly. The code runs but for some reason its not doing anything. For cells that contain "bloomberg" nothing is being detected. Any idea why?

Comment: Note that this code I've provided is specifically checking column C (which is the 3rd column).  What column do you want it to check?

Comment: If, according to your description, you want it to check column B, change the `Cells(a, 3)` within the `InStr` to be `Cells(a, 2)` so that it looks at column B.

Comment: I changed it to check column B (that being the column that has the values). Sadly it still runs but does nothing..

Comment: That's because your `lr` line is also invalid, change it to: `lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: It works! I accepted your answer. All of your comments have helped me better understand my problem. Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 3)
```